# Select value for each id after sorting on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, select, dense-rank

Looking for a way to select one "status" per "id1" based on the lowest "id2" then the MAX "the_date".  I was able to do this by creating multiple subqueries finding the min id2 per id1 first, then finding the max "the_date" per id2 and joining them back to the original table.  But it seems like there should a way to do this with one qry?

```
with data as(
Select 101 as id1, 11 as id2, to_date('01/02/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') as the_date, 'a' as status from dual union all
Select 101 as id1, 11 as id2, to_date('01/01/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') as the_date, 'b' as status from dual union all
Select 101 as id1, 24 as id2, to_date('01/02/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') as the_date, 'g' as status from dual union all
Select 200 as id1, 41 as id2, to_date('01/02/2017','MM/DD/YYYY') as the_date, 'c' as status from dual union all
Select 200 as id1, 61 as id2, to_date('01/02/2019','MM/DD/YYYY') as the_date, 'z' as status from dual)
```

The result of the qry should be:

```
id1|id2|the_date|status
101|11|'01/02/2019'|a
200|41|'01/02/2017'|c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id1 order by id2, the_date desc) as seqnum
      from data d
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=aeabab235c3ead22e69f0a05806814f0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you, this is so much more efficient than what I did.